# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89

Tags: python, csv

I want to read a csv file and process some columns but I keep getting issues.
Stuck with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\Python\read csv.py", line 5, in <module>
    for row in reader:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 446: invalid start byte
>>>
```

My Code

```
import csv
with open("c:\\Users\\Sven\\Desktop\\relaties 24112014.csv",newline='', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';',quotechar='|')
    #print(sum(1 for row in reader))
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        if row:
            value = row[6]
            value = value.replace('(', '')
            value = value.replace(')', '')
            value = value.replace(' ', '')
            value = value.replace('.', '')
            value = value.replace('0032', '0')
            if len(value) > 0:
                print(value + ' Length: ' + str(len(value)))
```

I'm a beginner with Python, tried googling, but hard to find the right solution.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: can you share your file csv file or parts of it ?

Comment: Are you sure that your file is *really* encoded with UTF-8? Try `'cp1252'` if the file comes from Excel in a western country. All supported encodings: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: Why are you opening the file as UTF-8? Are you certain that that's the correct codec for that file?

Comment: `89` is not a valid UTF8 byte, so the "error" is correct and your file is not UTF8-encoded. Case closed as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Try a `"latin1" encoding were all byte values will be legal.

Comment: Changing the encoding to "cp1252" fixed it - thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

**The first byte of a .PNG file is 0x89**. Not saying that is your problem, but the .PNG header is specifically designed so that it is **NOT** **accidentally interpreted as text**.

Why you would have a .csv file that is actually a .png I don't know. But it definitely could happen if someone accidentally renamed the file. On windows 10 every once and a while I accidentally mass-rename files by accident because of their stupid checkbox feature. Why Microsoft decided desktop machines having identical UI controls to tablets was I good idea... I don't know.

Comment: I am working with a file which is png, i.e. I know that it's png and it's supposed to be that, but I still get this error.

Answer (score 7):

This is the most important clue:

> invalid start byte

`\x89` is not, as suggested in the comments, an invalid UTF-8 byte. It is a completely valid **continuation** byte. Meaning if it follows the correct byte value, it codes UTF-8 correctly:

http://hexutf8.com/?q=0xc90x89

So either you (1) do not have UTF-8 data as you expect, or (2) you have some malformed UTF-8 data. The Python codec is simply letting you know that it encountered `\x89` in the wrong order in the sequence.

(More on continuation bytes here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout)

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the similar error when trying to read or upload the following kinds of files:

1. CSV File
2. JPEG File
3. PNG File
4. Zip File

The best way to avoid error like:

1. 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89
2. 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff

**is to read these files as Bytes. When you treat them as byte then you need not provide any encoding value here.** So when you open them you should specify:

`with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:`

Or in your case, the code should be something like:

`import csv`

`with open("c:\\Users\\Sven\\Desktop\\relaties 24112014.csv", newline='', 'rb') as f:`

```
reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';',quotechar='|')
```

Comment: this fixed me upload zip and jpeg files